# Xcode 5.1.1 Getting Error while installing CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am getting following error while installing Cocoa Pods.

```
...........

Successfully installed cocoapods-core-0.33.1
 Fetching: cocoapods-0.33.1.gem (100%) 
ERROR: Error installing cocoapods: cocoapods requires cocoapods-try (~> 0.3.0)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Which tutorial you followed for cocoa pods installation??, raywenderlich..?

Comment: @mAc Yes :).. Thats what i used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem and solved it as follows:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-try
```

After which I had a subsequent error when trying to install cocoapods:

```
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
cocoapods requires cocoapods-trunk (~> 0.1.1)
```

Which lead me to try:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-trunk
```

Finish up with one last sudo:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

And you should be good to go! Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe some unwanted problem may have occurred while installation, give a try by Uninstalling the cocapods and re installing it again like this  :-

```
1) Uninstall CocoaPods (choose to uninstall all versions):

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

2) Remove old master repo:

sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master

3) Install CocoaPods without sudo:

gem install cocoapods

4) Setup CocoaPods and Master repo:

pod setup
```

"sudo" keyword is used to tell OS you are giving command as an Admin, so do write sudo while installation (just mentioning for the safer side)

Comment: Now i am getting Permission error once i fire 3rd step:ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Comment: Hmm... do you have the admin right for the Machine ?, try with sudo then, sudo gem install cocoapods